# In a SQL database, how do I delete records from Table_B when matching id is already deleted from Table_A?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `Table_A` & `Table_B` where `Table_B.IX_Id = Table_A.IX_ID`. The records in these tables will look like as following:

QUERY:

```
   select * from Table_A where IX_ID = 4783 
   select * from Table_B where IX_Id = 4783
```

RESULT:

```
Table_A result

IX_ID       IX_ParentID          IX_CreationDate
----------- -------------------- --------------------
4783        0                    2015-01-26 10:23:00

Table_B result    

IX_Id       Row_Id      Document_Id
----------- ----------- -----------
4783        1           101 
4783        1           99
4783        1           94
```

Now let's say I have deleted a record from `Table_A` which is 4783 than what I want is, also delete records from `Table_B` where id is 4783.

I can get the deleted record from `Table_A` by following query:

QUERY:

```
;WITH Missing (missnum, maxid)
AS
(
 SELECT 1 AS missnum, (select max(IX_ID) from Table_A)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT missnum + 1, maxid FROM Missing
 WHERE missnum < maxid
)
SELECT missnum
FROM Missing
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_A missingIds on missingIds.IX_ID = Missing.missnum
WHERE missingIds.IX_ID is NULL  order by 1 desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

RESULT:

```
missnum
-----------
4783
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

Check that if `missnum` exists in `Table_B` than delete those matching records from `Table_B` else not. How can I achieve this?

NOTE: I have so many records deleted from `Table_A` and I am doing tune up in `Table_B` where corresponding records are in hundreds.

Comment: Normally you'd set up a foreign key with cascading delete, unless you needed more control at which point you'd go with a delete trigger.  Does this mean anything at all to you?

Comment: Well I am not pro in SQL so I don't think I understand your suggestion. As of now I just  want to delete those matching id records from Table_B. Sorry if this creates confusion.

Comment: You don't have to be a pro.  If you're using databases with relational data, you'd better have some REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY enforced by FOREIGN KEYS.  One of the benefits is that you can configure the foreign key with CASCADING DELETES which do exactly what you're asking here.  If you search for each ALL CAPS phrases you'll quickly learn how it works.  It's important stuff that, unless you learn it, will cause you MASSIVE (don't search for that one) headaches down the road.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NOT IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) to find things that don't match a subquery, which is much simpler and the query optimizer has a better chance of choosing something performant

```
DELETE FROM Table_B
WHERE IX_Id NOT IN (SELECT IX_Id FROM Table_A)
```

I agree with Will's comment about a foreign key if you want to keep IX_Id in Table_B in step with Table_A

Comment: I guess the question is whether `(SELECT IX_Id FROM Table_A)` returns the same list of distinct IDs as the original recursive CTE.  If so, then this is definitely the preferred approach, however  I wasn't sure is if it did, which is why I posted my more complicated answer.

Comment: the question is describing a foreign key, so even if there are things missed by the CTE, they should be sorted out here. IX_IDs in B that are negative or higher than MAX(Table_A..IX_ID) if they exist, would be missed

Answer (score 2):

Take this:

```
;WITH Missing (missnum, maxid)
AS
(
 SELECT 1 AS missnum, (select max(IX_ID) from Table_A)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT missnum + 1, maxid FROM Missing
 WHERE missnum < maxid
)
SELECT missnum
FROM Missing
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_A missingIds on missingIds.IX_ID = Missing.missnum
WHERE missingIds.IX_ID is NULL  order by 1 desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

And change it into this:

```
;WITH Missing (missnum, maxid)
AS
(
 SELECT 1 AS missnum, (select max(IX_ID) from Table_A)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT missnum + 1, maxid FROM Missing
 WHERE missnum < maxid
)
, Missing1 (missnum)
AS
(
 SELECT missnum
 FROM Missing
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_A missingIds on missingIds.IX_ID = Missing.missnum
 WHERE missingIds.IX_ID is NULL
)
DELETE FROM Table_B
WHERE IS_Id IN(SELECT missnum FROM Missing1)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```